# JavaFX animationTimer 144 fps

Tags: java, animation, javafx, frame-rate

I have a problem and i can not find any solution to this problem.

I am using an animationTimer to update everything and i try to fix it on 60fps as it should do it by itself. The Problem is that on my first screen it runs on 144 fps and on my second with 60fps. I have a Gsync monitor as my first screen and i think because i force Gsync the animationTimer is fixed to 144fps. Is there any method to prevent the animationTimer go further 60fps?

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            long elapsedNanosPerFrame = 0;
            long oldFrameTime = frameTimes[frameTimeIndex] ;
            double frameRate = 0;
            frameTimes[frameTimeIndex] = now ;
            frameTimeIndex = (frameTimeIndex + 1) % frameTimes.length ;
            if (frameTimeIndex == 0) {
                arrayFilled = true ;
            }
            if (arrayFilled) {
                long elapsedNanos = now - oldFrameTime ;
                elapsedNanosPerFrame = elapsedNanos / frameTimes.length ;
                while () {

                }
                frameRate = 1_000_000_000.0 / elapsedNanosPerFrame ;
                label.setText(String.format("Current frame rate: %.3f", frameRate));
                label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);

            }
            update(elapsedNanosPerFrame);
        }
    };
```

And yes it is not a visible Label bug or something, the gameplay is faster.

Comment: Unless you have some unusual (and experimental) system property settings, JavaFX should be capping the frame rate at 60fps: the monitor should be irrelevant. In general, to cap the frame rendering you would need to write code to do that. I recommend reading Stephen van Impe's excellent blog posts ([part 1](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) and [part 2](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html)) for some nice implementations.

Comment: thanks for your post. In the second blog post the fixed time steps would be a good choice i think. I will give it a try. But it do not give an answer to the first screen faster animationTimer updating "Bug".

Comment: Not directly, no. But anyway, you should not rely on the time between calls to `AnimationTimer.handle(...)` as these will (at least potentially) be variable anyway; I'd just measure the time steps and use the actual elapsed time to determine the update, maybe with a minimum time step. What platform (OS and JDK version) are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 and jdk1.8.0_65